# Using placeholders in a database query doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am querying a mysql  database version 5.6.13 using python 2.7.

This works:

```
whichCustomer = str(1934)
qry = ("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid = " + whichCustomer)
cursor.execute(qry)
```

The query also works:

```
qry = ("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid = 1934")
cursor.execute(qry)
```

BUT, when I try to use string substitution the query fails:

```
whichCustomer = 1934
qry = ("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid = %d")
cursor.execute(qry, (whichCustomer))
```

Is there something I am missing.  The full try/execute code follows:

```
try:
    import mysql.connector
    print 'Module mysql initialized'
    print 'Attempting connection to cheer database' 
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='notsure', 
            password='notsure',
            host='localhost',
            database='notreal')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    whichCustomer = str(1934)
    qry = ("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid = " + whichCustomer)
    cursor.execute(qry)
    recx = cursor.fetchone()
    print recx[1]
    cnx.close()
    print 'Successful connection to notreal database'
except:
    print 'Error initialzing mysql databsasr'
```

Comment: Make sure you report exactly what "doesn't work": if there is an error, this should include the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `%s` for SQL parameters, and the second argument must be a sequence, like a tuple:

```
whichCustomer = 1934
qry = ("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid = %s")
cursor.execute(qry, (whichCustomer,))
```

Note the comma in the second parameter; without a comma, that parameter is *not* a tuple and just the `1934` integer value is passed in instead.

Although both Python string interpolation placeholders and SQL parameters use closely related syntax, they are *not* the same thing. As such, SQL parameters for positional values are *always* expressed as `%s` regardless of the type.